# Method (Delete or add) of Object Listrow failed (then crash) VBA

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am coding a userform to add, edit and delete data from a table located in the workbook.
With the addition of a new row into the table, I give the row a unique number. When the user in the form double clicks in the Listbox *(listbox contains the table from the sheet)* on the line they want to remove.
the data is being returned to the boxes inside the form(same as used to add data).
The removal of the row relies on a unique number and uses that to search the table for the row to delete.
that nr is then located in me.Nr
when I try to add or delete the data it works mostly but it will error suddenly (no idea when the error occurred when it occurs). So it happens randomly, sometimes I can add or delete the whole listing in the table and sometimes it occurs just after adding or deleting a few rows.

For my lack of coding skills, it is very hard to say where the error occurss

**the error is:**
*-2147417848 Method "(delete or add) of object listrow failed*

**the error that is thrown up at delete code is here:**
*lo.ListRows(rw).Delete*

**Error on add code is here:**
*Set newrow = tbl.ListRows.Add(AlwaysInsert:=True)*

When the errors are thrown up the sheet just crashes and the whole file crashes.

1. I have tried putting [alwaysinstert:=True] at the end of Set newrow =
   ws.ListObjects("plandata").ListRows.Add
2. Put every Private sub to normal Sub (Internet suggested that)

I cannot find more suggestions for fixing this error.

I appreciate any help or advice that you can give me, as I am new to VBA and trying to learn.

Thanks in advance,

Yede

**Sub for Delete:**

```
    Sub Deletebtn_Click()
    Dim lo As ListObject
    Dim cDelete As VbMsgBoxResult
    Dim num As Long
    Set lo = Sheets("Planningdata").ListObjects("Plandatag")
    
    'error statement
        On Error GoTo errHandler:
    'hold in memory and stop screen flicker
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'check for values
        If Nr.Value = "" Or dagweek.Value = "" Then
            MsgBox "There is not data to delete"
        Exit Sub
        End If
    'give the user a chance to change their mind
        cDelete = MsgBox("Are you sure that you want to delete the data?", _
        vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "Are you sure????")
        If cDelete = vbYes Then
    
            For cl = 1 To lo.HeaderRowRange.Count
                If lo.HeaderRowRange(cl) = "Nr" Then Exit For
            Next
    
                num = Me.Nr.Value
    
            For rw = lo.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
                If lo.DataBodyRange(rw, cl) = num Then
                lo.ListRows(rw).Delete
            End If
        Next
        End If
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub
    errHandler:
    'show error information in a messagebox
    MsgBox "An Error has Occurred " & vbCrLf & "The error number is: " & _
    Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description & vbCrLf & "Please notify the administrator"
    End Sub
```

**Sub for Save:**

```
Sub Savebtn_Click()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim newrow As ListRow
Dim Last_row As Long

Application.EnableEvents = False

Set ws = Sheets("Planningdata")
Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Plandatag")
On Error Resume Next
Set newrow = tbl.ListRows.Add(AlwaysInsert:=True)
On Error GoTo 0
DoEvents

Last_row = ws.Range("B10000").End(xlUp).Row
DoEvents

ws.Range("B" & Last_row) = "=ROW()-4"
ws.Range("C" & Last_row) = Me.Analyse.Value
ws.Range("D" & Last_row) = Me.dagweek.Value
ws.Range("E" & Last_row) = "=CONCAT(Plandatag[@Analyse],""-"",Plandatag[@Dag])"
ws.Range("F" & Last_row) = Me.Samplenr.Value
ws.Range("G" & Last_row) = Me.Apparaat.Value
DoEvents
Application.EnableEvents = True
Unload Me
Toevoegen.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: [Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53012330/vba-listobject-wont-add-rows?rq=1)?

Comment: @garbb Thanks, I will look into that!

Comment: @garbb  At this moment adding Planlist.Rowsource = "" right after the dim statements and adding the rowsource back when resetting the form keeps the errors away for now. i will test it very hard in the next weeks. Thanks for showing me that thread. cheers.